# When using LibTorch for semantic segmentation model deployment in MFC, mudule.forward() breaks abnormally when doing GPU inference

Tags: c++, mfc, libtorch

When I use LibTorch library to do GPU reasoning in MFC, when executing to `Module.forward()`, the program always breaks due to unhandled exception. Have you ever encountered this problem? And how are they solved? When I load `torch::jit::load(model_path);`, there is no error. My forward inference execution code was executed in a C++ thread, but I'm not sure if this error has anything to do with the design. I also wrote a console program that did the same GPU reasoning, and it passed without an exception, but with an interrupt error in MFC. There are no exceptions in CPU reasoning.

I think there is a correspondence between the LibTorch version and CUDA version, but the fact that the same environment and configuration can be executed under the console application (cmd) does not explain it.

[image: Image1]

[image: Image2]